# Uniform continuity of $f(x) = x^2$ on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Using the definition of continuity (epsilon-delta), carefully show that $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$

To start this problem, I was taking a delta that does not depend on points in the interval[-1,1]. and I know we want to show that for p,q in [-1,1] want to show that for |p-q|

Comment: *Hint:* Use the Mean Value Theorem to put an upper bound of the difference quotient $$\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\right|$$ This will enable you to find a $\delta$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
|x^2-y^2|=|x+y||x-y|\leq 2|x-y|
$$

Comment: so then delta=epsilon/2 and you are done?

Comment: Yep.${}{}{}{}{}{}$